# RequestTimeoutException when using MassTransit 8 requests in LINQPad 7

Tags: .net, rabbitmq, masstransit, linqpad

Still new to MassTransit and encountering problems when trying to use MT8 requests in LINQPad scripts. I have a RabbitMQ management instance spun up locally in Docker, which works with .NET console apps, but I must be missing some requirements for using MT8 directly from LINQPad 7.

Here's a basic example I made to demonstrate my error:

```
async Task Main()
{
    IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
    services.AddMassTransit(x =>
    {
        x.AddConsumer(typeof(MyConsumer));

        x.UsingRabbitMq((ctx, cfg) =>
        {
            cfg.Host("localhost", 5672, "/", h =>
            {
                h.Username("guest");
                h.Password("guest");
            });

            cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(ctx);
        });
    }); 
    var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    
    var bus = serviceProvider.GetService<IBus>();
    var response = await bus.Request<MyRequest, MyResponse>(new MyRequest("Hi there"));
    response.Message.Dump("Response");
}

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class MyRequest
    {
        public MyRequest() { }

        public MyRequest(string phrase)
        {
            Phrase = phrase;
        }

        public string Phrase { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyResponse
    {
        public MyResponse() { }

        public MyResponse(string phrase)
        {
            Phrase = phrase;
        }

        public string Phrase { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyConsumer : IConsumer<MyRequest>
    {
        public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<MyRequest> context)
        {
            await context.RespondAsync(new MyResponse($"'{context.Message.Phrase}' to you too!"));
        }
    }
}
```

My RabbitMQ container seems to receive the message (and create a temporary exchange), but not be able to route it back...

[image]

Then after 30 seconds, the exception is thrown:

> RequestTimeoutException: Timeout waiting for response

[image]

Messages **send** correctly from LINQPad with this method, and consumers set up in .NET console apps can consume them fine. But I can't make request/responses from LINQPad, which is my ultimate goal here.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, it's been years since I've seen anyone use LINQpad.

And even longer since I've had to tell people they need to *start the bus*.

MassTransit uses a hosted service to start the bus, which is normally invoked by the underlying generic host built into .NET.

Since you aren't using the host, you'll need get `IBusControl` from the container and start the bus. And yes, you'll need to stop it as well after you're done.

Comment: Chris, you're brilliant. That was the missing piece and it's working beautifully now. Many thanks!